# Pytorch Geometric: How do I pass the 2nd or 3rd arguments to from_networkx?

Tags: pytorch, networkx, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to use [from_networkx()](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html#torch_geometric.utils.from_networkx) from Pytorch Geometric.  I have a networkx Graph object as my first argument, and am trying to feed in a list of strings for the node attribute.  I am getting an error that I am giving it 2 positional arguments when it wants 1.  How can I make this code function or find a workaround?

The first line below is a list of attributes produced by nx.get_attributes(I, 'spin').

```
{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 1, (0, 2): -1, (0, 3): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 1, (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): -1, (2, 2): -1, (2, 3): 1, (3, 0): -1, (3, 1): -1, (3, 2): 1, (3, 3): -1}
Graph with 16 nodes and 32 edges
<class 'networkx.classes.graph.Graph'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytorch_test.py", line 222, in <module>
    print(from_networkx(I, ["spin"]))
TypeError: from_networkx() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Please include next time a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are running `pytorch_geometric` with version <= 1.7.2. Then the method [`from_networkx`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/modules/utils.html#torch_geometric.utils.from_networkx) had only one parameter. Only the latest [`from_networkx`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html#torch_geometric.utils.from_networkx) has the additional parameters.

However, before the additional parameters were introduced-and still the default behaviour- all node attributes were transformed:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.karate_club_graph()
print(g.nodes(data=True))
# [(0, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (1, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (2, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), ....
import torch
from torch_geometric.utils import from_networkx

data = from_networkx(g)

print(data)
#Data(club=[34], edge_index=[2, 156])
```

So in your example, `data.spin` should work if you use `from_networkx(I)`.